# How to disable cell truncation in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have data frame:

```
SUMMARY                     VERB EXISTING   NOUN
FULL: CHANGE OF USE FROM 
DWELLING (C3) TO REGI...    NaN             Jess
```

Which option should I choose to see the whole cell content?

It's pandas dataframe, I've set some like

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000
pd.options.display.width = 1000
```

but still no result.

---

#### #'s

Get rid of ellipsis
Make columns wider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`pd.set_option`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWSvN.png) and `'display.max_colwidth'`

```
pd.set_option(
    'display.max_colwidth', 100
)
```

---

From Docs

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works. Can I ask, for example, is it possible to set max height to set columns less wide and more high or is it just fit automatically and I don't need to be worried?

Comment: I posted a picture that is copied from the docs that shows the example.  Also the link that goes to the docs with the example.

Answer (score 0):

To disable cell truncation regardless of the length of the value/string in your cell, you can use the new and simple syntax of [pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html?highlight=pd%20set_option.display.max_colwidth) with `display.max_colwidth` st to `None`: `pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)`. It'll override the default width of 50 characters.